# RSpec Rails Test Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to optimise my specs a bit. I usually have a problem creating test data for nested resources and users. I usually end up with a before(:each) that sets up the data, this is run by more than 120 of my specs. Let me show you: (it's not accurate, but you should get the point)

```rspec
def setup_test_data
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_with_account)
  @account = @user.account
  3.times do |n|
    list = FactoryGirl.create(:list)
    list.items << FactoryGirl.create_list(:item, 3)
    @account.lists << list
  end  
end

before(:each){setup_test_data}

subject{List.merge(list1, list2)}
it{should have(6).items}
```

And here is why I fail to shorten my test data setup

```rails
def self.merge(lists)
  merged_list = lists.first.account.subscriber_lists.build
  name = "Merge of "
  lists.each do |list|
    name << "'#{list.name}', "
    list.items.each do |item|
      merged_list.items.build(item.dup.attributes)
    end
  end
  merged_list.name = name.chop.chop
  merged_list.save!
  merged_list.reload # I use this to filter out duplicates via validations
end
```

My Options:
A) move some logic back into the controller, less dependency on the account, save in the controller
B) stub/mock a lot more, but with nested resources + associations it's hard to do

C) your idea here:

Thanks
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C) Create your own RSpec rake task that will first import some basic data, then use DatabaseCleaner to make sure everything runs transactionally (you will have to manually clear the DB after your custom rake tasks, because for some reason it doesn't seem to be, but with DatabaseCleaner this is a one-liner).

I use this in a situation where I have a large pre-defined dataset that I need to test against and want it to be created once, then have tests performed transactionally against it.

If this appeals to you, let me know and I can provide more code to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that would probably be the best way too. I setup a bunch of fixtures using fixture_builder, then have my setup_data method just pull them from the database. I'm still struggling a bit with factory sequences and how exactly DatabaseCleaner works. But I really don't want to mock and stub that much, a bit of integration testing with each spec has served me well in the past. It's just slower and doesn't always come with pretty code.

Comment: Well if you have more questions feel free to ask! Factory girl has pretty good documentation and so does DatabaseCleaner on their GitHub pages, so that's a good place to start. Mocking and stubbing isn't something you should shy away though, because tests are important and they can help you from writing repeated tests or "bad" tests, in short.